# Jersey with Spring 4 Dependency Injection

Tags: java, spring, rest, jakarta-ee, jersey

I am to use Dependency Injection of Spring framework version 4. I have seen that the Jersey has its DI with plugin
`<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.ext</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-spring3</artifactId>
    <version>2.12</version>
</dependency>`

Is Jersey's DI of Spring  recommended or is there special reason to use it? What if Spring 4 DI is used independently ?

Also please let me know any step by step learning source to integration Spring DI with Jersey ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `jersey-spring3` extension is not a stand-alone Dependency Injection feature, it's just an extension which makes Jersey aware of Spring's managed beans.

From [Jersey - Spring DI](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/spring.html):

> Jersey provides an extension to support Spring DI. This enables Jersey to use Spring beans as JAX-RS components (e.g. resources and providers) and also allows Spring to inject into Jersey managed components.
>
> ...
>
> The above module does not add any transitive dependency to Spring modules, so you will need to add Spring 3 dependencies explicitly into your dependency list.

So if you want to use Jersey with Spring you need `jersey-spring3` and all the Spring dependencies you normally use.

By the way, the `jersey-spring3` extension is compiled against Spring 3, but should work with Spring 4. See [Using Jersey-spring with Spring 4.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21443088/using-jersey-spring-with-spring-4-0) for reference.

Answer (score -2):

You should  add `jersey-spring3.jar` first  like the document in jersey website.
For this **`step by step learning source to integration Spring DI with Jersey`**, you can  do  like  this  when you start up you application debug the application.

Find `ServletContainer.class` and set a ***`breakpoint`*** in `init()`  function, as this  you can find this  step by step.

Comment: protected void init(WebConfig webConfig)
    ----- this.containerListener.onStartup(this);