# How to make a JAX-RS annotated singleton class EAGERLY instantiated

Tags: java, singleton, jax-rs, instantiation, eager

I am using Jax-RS 2.0 with Jersey 2.22.1 and Java SE 8, deployed in Tomcat 8.0.30.
I have the POJO annotated with the appropriate JAX-RS annotations, and its working as expected. I have also annotated the POJO with `@Singleton`. The class gets lazily instantiated as a singleton, which is the expected behavior of `@Singleton`. But I would like to instantiated the class eagerly, at application startup. Is there a way to do that? I have looked at the `@Startup` annotation but unfortunately, that is part of the EJB package and I am not using EJB's (nor would I like to import the EJB jar file).

I am also using the Springframework 4.2.4 which would by default eagerly instantiate singletons when using the `@Service` or `@Component` annotations but unfortunately, I cannot use those annotations on a JAX-RS POJO (this is why the class extends from `SpringBeanAutowiringSupport`.

I have attached the java code but since its working as expected I'm not sure that would add anything useful.

```
import javax.inject.Singleton;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;
import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.PUT;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.FormParam;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import org.xxx.profile.util.GeneralUtil;
import org.xxx.profile.util.WebServiceLogger;
import org.xxx.profile.util.datatransfer.AccountDTO;
import org.xxx.profile.web.exception.RestException;
import org.xxx.profile.web.exception.FailureResponse;
import org.springframework.web.context.support.SpringBeanAutowiringSupport;


@Singleton
@Path( "account" )
public class AccountWebService  extends SpringBeanAutowiringSupport{


    @Autowired
    private AccountLogic accountLogic;

    @Autowired
    protected SimpleParser simplerParser;


    @GET
    @Path("get/{id: [a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z_0-9]*}")
    @Produces( MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON )
    @Consumes( MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON )
    public AccountDTO retrieveAccount(@PathParam("id") String customerId) throws RestException {
        try {
            return accountLogic.retrieveAccount(customerId);
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            String transactionID = GeneralUtil.getUniqueID();
            WebServiceLogger.severe( transactionID, "Unable to retrieve an account for the customerId: " + customerId, e, this.getClass() );
            throw new RestException( new FailureResponse( FailureResponse.Status.FAIL, "add user friendly message here", transactionID ), e );
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

See [Jersey 2.22.1 User Guide](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/spring.html):

> If you want to use Jersey Spring DI support you will need to add the jersey-spring3 module into the list of your dependencies:
>
> ```
> <dependency>
>     <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.ext</groupId>
>     <artifactId>jersey-spring3</artifactId>
>     <version>2.22.1</version>
> </dependency>
> ```

It seems to work for Spring 4, too. See [Question 21443088](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21443088/using-jersey-spring-with-spring-4-0)

Comment: BTW... the following post will help resolve any spring context exceptions that are thrown when using jersey-spring3  with no spring configuration file (100% annotation driven)...  https://java.net/jira/browse/JERSEY-2038